# Handling data and target scaling with both Pipeline and TransformedTargetRegressor on nested regressors

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to use both Pipeline and TransformedTargetRegressor to handle all the scaling (on data and target) on BaggingRegressor and all of its estimators.

My first try works fine (no use of Pipeline and TransformedTargetRegressor)

```
$ cat test1.py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR

def f(x):
    return x*np.cos(x) + np.random.normal(size=500)*2

def main():
    # Generate random data.
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
    rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
    rng.shuffle(x)
    x = np.sort(x[:])
    y = f(x)

    # Plot random data.
    fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 10))
    axis.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black', markersize=2, label='random data')

    # Create bagging models.
    model = BaggingRegressor(n_estimators=5, base_estimator=SVR())
    x_augmented = np.array([x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5]).T
    model.fit(x_augmented, y)

    # Plot intermediate regression estimations.
    axis.plot(x, model.predict(x_augmented), '-', color='red', label=model.__class__.__name__)
    for i, tree in enumerate(model.estimators_):
        y_pred = tree.predict(x_augmented)
        axis.plot(x, y_pred, '--', label='tree '+str(i))

    axis.axis('off')
    axis.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which is OK : bagging regressor is superimposed to all estimators

[image]

Now I want to use Pipeline and TransformedTargetRegressor to handle all the scaling on data and targets but it doesn't work, as bagging scale differs from estimator scales :

```
$ cat test2.py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

def f(x):
    return x*np.cos(x) + np.random.normal(size=500)*2

def main():
    # Generate random data.
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
    rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
    rng.shuffle(x)
    x = np.sort(x[:])
    y = f(x)

    # Plot random data.
    fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 10))
    axis.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black', markersize=2, label='random data')

    # Create bagging models.
    model = BaggingRegressor(n_estimators=5, base_estimator=SVR())
    x_augmented = np.array([x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5]).T
    pipe = Pipeline([('scale', preprocessing.StandardScaler()), ('model', model)])
    treg = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipe, transformer=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler())
    treg.fit(x_augmented, y)

    # Plot intermediate regression estimations.
    axis.plot(x, treg.predict(x_augmented), '-', color='red', label=model.__class__.__name__)
    for i, tree in enumerate(treg.regressor_['model'].estimators_):
        y_hat = tree.predict(x_augmented)
        y_transformer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(y.reshape(-1, 1))
        y_pred = y_transformer.inverse_transform(y_hat.reshape(-1, 1))
        axis.plot(x, y_pred, '--', label='tree '+str(i))
    axis.axis('off')
    axis.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

How to handle scaling properly on bagging regressor and all of it's nested estimators ?

The diff between the 2 tests is to use Pipeline and TransformedTargetRegressor

```
$ diff test1.py  test2.py
7a8,10
> from sklearn import preprocessing
> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
> from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
27c30,32
<     model.fit(x_augmented, y)
---
>     pipe = Pipeline([('scale', preprocessing.StandardScaler()), ('model', model)])
>     treg = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipe, transformer=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler())
>     treg.fit(x_augmented, y)
30,32c35,39
<     axis.plot(x, model.predict(x_augmented), '-', color='red', label=model.__class__.__name__)
<     for i, tree in enumerate(model.estimators_):
<         y_pred = tree.predict(x_augmented)
---
>     axis.plot(x, treg.predict(x_augmented), '-', color='red', label=model.__class__.__name__)
>     for i, tree in enumerate(treg.regressor_['model'].estimators_):
>         y_hat = tree.predict(x_augmented)
>         y_transformer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(y.reshape(-1, 1))
>         y_pred = y_transformer.inverse_transform(y_hat.reshape(-1, 1))
```

**EDIT**

Tried to use the `tranformer_` member of the `TransformedTargetRegressor` instance : test3 (same as test2 up to the following diff) fails too !...

```
$ diff test2.py test3.py
38c38
<         y_transformer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(y.reshape(-1, 1))
---
>         y_transformer = treg.transformer_
```

Comment: If the solution could be generic enough to work too with `RandomForest` (regressor, classifier) and friends (AdaBoost, GradientBoosting), it would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are issues with your code but rather with the plotting part.

```py
# Plot intermediate regression estimations.
    axis.plot(x, treg.predict(x_augmented), '-', color='red', label=model.__class__.__name__)
    for i, tree in enumerate(treg.regressor_['model'].estimators_):
        y_hat = tree.predict(x_augmented)
        y_transformer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(y.reshape(-1, 1))
        y_pred = y_transformer.inverse_transform(y_hat.reshape(-1, 1))
        axis.plot(x, y_pred, '--', label='tree '+str(i))
```

`tree` here will be an `SVR()` and you are predicting on `x_augmented` while in the previous part, `x_augmented` was scaled with a `StandardScaler`. Thus the predictions are not corresponding to what you are expecting.

So by changing the code with the following snippet, you will be fine:

```py
# Plot intermediate regression estimations.
axis.plot(x, treg.predict(x_augmented), '-', color='red', label=model.__class__.__name__)
for i, tree in enumerate(treg.regressor_['model'].estimators_):
    x_augmented_scaled = treg.regressor_.named_steps['scale'].transform(x_augmented)
    y_hat = tree.predict(x_augmented_scaled)
    y_transformer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(y.reshape(-1, 1))
    y_pred = y_transformer.inverse_transform(y_hat.reshape(-1, 1))
    axis.plot(x, y_pred, '--', label='tree '+str(i))
axis.axis('off')
axis.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks !